# what does this type int * ( * ) ( int * ) represent in c language?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

Can anybody explain exactly what this type means `int * (*) (int *)` in C language?

Thanks,

Comment: [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+*+%28*foo%29+%28int+*%29%3B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless `int` is defined as a macro, `int * (*) (int *)` contains neither any constants nor any identifiers, therefore it cannot be an expression.  Rather, it is a *type*.  Specifically, it is the type of a pointer to a function that accepts one parameter, of type `int *`, and returns a value of type `int *`.  For example, it is compatible with a pointer to this function:

```
int *foo(int *x) {
    return x + 1;
}
```

You might use it in a typecast expression, such as in this contrived example:

```
int *(*p)() = foo;
int *(*p2)(int *) = (int * (*)(int *)) p;
// here ------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
int * (*) (int *); /* not valid expression */
```

is not a valid syntax in `C`. You might want to know

```
int * (*func) (int *); /* valid : function pointer declaration */
```

where `func` is a **function pointer**, can point to a function which takes input argument of `int*` type and which returns `int*`.

Comment: It is valid syntax. If you remove the variable `func`, you're left with its type: a pointer to a function whose signature is what you described.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. In C++, using this **valid syntax** of C, I can declare a `vector` of pointers to functions that have that signature. As in `std::vector<int * (*) (int *)> myfuncs;`

Answer (score 1):

You have to read about "left-right" rule on reading C declrations. 
Here is the link provides instructions. Rather than giving anwser this will help you learn the stuff to practice on your own.
http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ricko/rt_lt.rule.html